# If $p$ is a prime prove that $x^{p-1} - x^{p-2} + x^{p-3}- \cdots -x+1$ is irreducible over $Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

If $p$ is a prime prove that $x^{p-1} - x^{p-2} + x^{p-3}- \cdots -x+1$ is irreducible over $Q$.

**$1$st Attempt:** $x^{p-1} - x^{p-2} + x^{p-3}- \cdots -x+1 $

$= x^{p-2}(x-1)+x^{p-4}(x-1)+ \cdots ....x(x-1)+1$

$=(x-1)(x^{p-2}+x^{p-4}+ \cdots+x)+1$

I don't have much idea on how to move forward.

**$2$nd Atempt:** Using Fermat's theorem : if $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p~;~(a \ne p)$

Let $x=m/n$ such that $m,n \in Z ~;~\gcd(m,n)=1$. Then if

$f(x) = x^{p-1} - x^{p-2} + x^{p-3}- \cdots -x+1 $

$n^{p-1}f(x) = g(x)=m^{p-1} -n.m^{p-2}+n^2.m^{p-3}-\cdots-n^{p-2}m+n^{p-1}~~\in~~Z[x]$

I am not able to see how fermat's theorem can be used cleverly enough to make a difference here.

**$3$rd Attempt:** $\mod p$ irreducibility test and Eisenstein's Criterion, which can be brought into the required format only perhaps by substituting $g(x+a)$, again tedious.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $ $ If suffices to prove irreducible $\rm\,f(x) = g(-x) = (x^p-1)/(x-1).\,$ Eisenstein's Criterion applies to polynomials that have the form $\rm\, f \,\equiv\, x^n\pmod p.\,$ $\rm\,f\,$ is not of that form, but it's close

$$\rm f\, = \dfrac{x^p-1}{x-1} \equiv \dfrac{(x-1)^p}{x-1}\equiv (x-1)^{p-1}\pmod p$$

Eisenstein's Criterion may apply if you can find a map $\ \sigma\ $ that sends $\rm\ (x-1)^{p-1}\ $ to a power of $\rm\ x\ $ and, further, $\ \sigma\ $ preserves factorizations $\rm\ \sigma(gh)\ =\ \sigma g\cdot \sigma h\ $ (so we can pullback the irreducibility of $\rm\ \sigma\:f\ $ to $\rm\:f\:\!).\:$ For this, it suffices to find a  find an automorphism $\:\sigma\:$ on $\rm\, \Bbb Z[x]\, $ that shifts $\rm\:x\!-\!1\to x.\, $ Any ideas?

Comment: Uhmm .. I think I get something.  $f(x) = \dfrac{x^p-1}{x-1} = x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+....x+1$. $f(-x)$ give us us the required polynomial.

if we shift $x-1 \rightarrow x$,we get a polynomial in Eisenstein's format. Am i correct? Thanks

Comment: @VHP Yes, that the idea. Eisenstein applies to powers of $\,x\,$ and the input is a power of $\,x\,$ that is shifted $\,x\to x-1,\,$ so we need to unshift in order to apply Eisenstein (and shifts are automorphisms so they preserves factorizations, so also (ir)reducibility).

Comment: Oh ok .. So, all we need to prove is that this mapping is an automorphism now? and since an automorphism preserves factorization, we will be done

Comment: @VHP Right, the rest is straightforward.

Comment: Thanks. To show operation preservation for the mapping $\Psi(x) = x-1 : \Psi(xy) = xy \ne \Psi(x) \Psi(y)$ . I guess I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Do we really need to show automorphism. Won't this theorem suffice:  If $f(x+a)$ is irreducible over $F$, then $F$ is irreducible over $F$. Thanks

Comment: I got this. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: when $p$ is odd apply Eisenstein with the substitution $x = -(y+1)$

Comment: Oh! I did think about this method but later backed out :-)

Comment: @VHP See my answer for one way to *discover* this idea.